# Catch Tweets with JSON and sort by likes?

Tags: php, json, wordpress, twitter

I am currently running a wordpress backend and want to display some tweets based on hastags on my website. For the general API request and database storage, I use this function:

```
private function parseRequest($json) {
    $tmp = $json;
    $result = array();

    if (isset($json['statuses'])) {
        $tmp = $json['statuses'];
    }
    if (isset($tmp) && is_array($tmp)){
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $this->image = null;
            $this->media = null;
            $tc = new \stdClass();
            $tc->feed_id = $this->id();
            $tc->id = $t['id_str'];
            $tc->type = $this->getType();
            $tc->nickname = '@'.$t['user']['screen_name'];
            $tc->screenname = (string)$t['user']['name'];
            $tc->userpic = str_replace('.jpg', '_200x200.jpg', str_replace('_normal', '', (string)$t['user']['profile_image_url']));
            $tc->system_timestamp = strtotime($t['created_at']);
            $tc->text = $this->getText($t);
            $tc->userlink = 'https://twitter.com/'.$t['user']['screen_name'];
            $tc->permalink = $tc->userlink . '/status/' . $tc->id;
            $tc->media = $this->getMedia($t);
            @$tc->additional = array('shares' => (string)$t['retweet_count'], 'likes' => (string)$t['favorite_count'], 'comments' => (string)$t['reply_count']);
            if ($this->isSuitablePost($tc)) $result[$tc->id] = $tc;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Now I am looking for a function that counts all the variable in the "additional array together e.g. shares + likes + comments and sorts all posts based on the resulting number.
I am using the standard wordpress sql database. I cannot find a solution or I am just blind.

Thanks in regards

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function:

```
usort($tc, function($a, $b) {

    $a_sum = array_sum($a->additional);
    $b_sum = array_sum($b->additional);

    if ($a_sum == $b_sum) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a_sum < $b_sum) ? -1 : 1;
});
```